# pass character strings to ggplot2 within a function

Tags: string, r, ggplot2

Often I use [ggplot2](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/) in my work and build wrapper functions to speed up my work flow.  The use of the non-standard evaluation (NSE) [`aes`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/aes.html) forces me to use the actual variable names rather than passing character strings.  So I copy and rename dataframes and variable names to appease ggplot2.  There's got to be a better way.  How can I make [ggplot2](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/) accept unknown dataframes and column names via a function wrapper without replicating the dataframe and using generic column names?

**This works:**

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=hp)) +
    geom_point()
```

**This does not:**

```
FUN <- function(dat, x, y) {
    ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
        geom_point()
}

FUN(mtcars, "mpg", "hp")
```

Comment: Tired of hunting for duplicates? :)

Comment: @Joran I know this has to be a duplicate but couldn't find it.  I hope the title is likely to lead a searcher here.  If someone has a better title or additional tags feel free to edit.

Comment: I'm with Tyler. If the Masters of the SO Universe want to reward dupe-hunting, it is in their power to ordain such. As far as I can tell that is not the case. For this one I can remember hunting quite a while within the none-too-complete help pages for ggplot2 before I found this item. Has anyone else followed the "see _facet_" only to be extremely dissappointed at the nothingness one finds there?

Comment: For future searchers: There is a small description of ```aes_string()``` in page 15 of the [Documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/ggplot2.pdf). **Description**
Aesthetic mappings describe how variables in the data are mapped to visual properties (aesthetics)
of geoms. Compared to aes this function operates on strings rather than expressions. **Details**
aes_string is particularly useful when writing functions that create plots because you can use
strings to deﬁne the aesthetic mappings, rather than having to mess around with expressions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is now recommended to use `.data` pronoun

```
FUN <- function(dat, x, y) {
  ggplot(dat, aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]])) +
    geom_point()
}

FUN(mtcars, "mpg", "hp")
```

[image]

Couple of other alternatives -

```
#Using get
FUN <- function(dat, x, y) {
  ggplot(dat, aes(x = get(x), y = get(y))) +
    geom_point()
}

#Using sym

FUN <- function(dat, x, y) {
  ggplot(dat, aes(x = !!sym(x), y = !!sym(y))) +
    geom_point()
}
```

Answer (score 51):

There's the [`aes_string`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/aes_string.html) function, that I don't really see given prominence, which does exactly this:

```
FUN <- function(dat, x, y) {
    ggplot(dat, aes_string(x = x, y = y)) +
        geom_point()
}

FUN(mtcars, "mpg", "hp")
```

Comment: `aes_string` is soft deprecated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55133909/5477070 for a more up to date answer.