# r code: How can I use a variable name as a string to easily change variables in a formula?

Tags: r, dataframe, variables

I have a graph I'm making with multiple calls to x and y using the same dataset.

I want to be able to something like

```
x <- "variable_1"
y <- "variable_2"
y.min <- 100
```

so that I can have

```
data %>%
filter(y > y.min)
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
```

Therefore, if I change x to "variable_3", running the ggplot will display variable_3 on the x-axis instead of variable_1. Also, if I change the y variable, it will filter correctly

Comment: This can be done by the aes_string parameter instead of aes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826352/pass-character-strings-to-ggplot2-within-a-function. For dplyr-functions you can use rlang::sym: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121728/programming-with-dplyr-using-string-as-input

Comment: Thanks. That works for the ggplot area, but doesn't work for the filter part. What would I use for that?

Comment: it should be enough to wrinte filter(!!sym(y) > y.min) - hopefully :)

Answer (score -1):

get everything into a string and then execute the string using eval(parse(text = "stringFormula"))