# Define ggplot2 aesthetics from a list programatically without aes_string

Tags: ggplot2, nse, aesthetics

I have a list of aesthetics constructed programmatically and passed from other functions. They may contain any combination of aesthetics like alpha, colour, fill, etc., which is not know beforehand.

```
my_aes_list <- list(
    x = "cty",
    y = "hwy",
    col = "trans")
```

I can use [`aes_string`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html) to create aesthetics programmatically from this list:

```
library(ggplot2)
my_aes <- do.call(ggplot2::aes_string, my_aes_list)
ggplot(mpg) + geom_point(my_aes)
```

However `aes_string()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.0.0 and I would like to replace this code before it gets removed in a future version.

The [documented alternative](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html) and [several](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22309285/333599) [stack overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19826352/333599) indicate to use the `.data[[` pronoun. However I can't find out how to use it with arbitrary programmatic aesthetics.

Doing something like:

```
my_data_list <- list()
for (name in names(my_aes_list)) {
    my_data_list[[name]] <- .data[[my_aes_list[name]]]
}
```

obviously doesn't work outside of the `aes` call itself. I also tried the `!!!` injectors to no avail:

```
ggplot(mpg) + geom_point(aes(!!!my_aes_list))
```

seems to work but doesn't plot correctly.

What's the proper way to replace `aes_string` and call `ggplot` in this context?

Answer (score 1):

One solution I found is to ["defuse" the evaluation](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-defuse.html) of the `.data[[` pronoun with a call to `expr()`:

```
my_data_list <- lapply(my_aes_list, function(x) ggplot2::expr(.data[[x]]))
```

Later, `ggplot2::aes()` transparently evaluates these expressions:

```
my_aes <- do.call(ggplot2::aes, my_data_list)
ggplot(mpg) + geom_point(my_aes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem; another potential solution is to 'enquo(ensym(list))' then use the `!!!` operator, i.e.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

my_aes_list <- list(
  x = "cty",
  y = "hwy",
  col = "trans")

my_list_quos <- as_quosures(map(my_aes_list, sym), env = .GlobalEnv)
my_list_quos
#> <list_of<quosure>>
#> 
#> $x
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^cty
#> env:  global
#> 
#> $y
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^hwy
#> env:  global
#> 
#> $col
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^trans
#> env:  global

ggplot(mpg) + geom_point(aes(!!!my_list_quos))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The '[tinycodet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tinycodet/index.html)' R package provides `aes_pro()`, which is equivalent to `ggplot2::aes()`, except it uses formula inputs instead of non-standard evaluation. So you can do the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
data("mpg", package = "ggplot2")
my_aes_list <- list(
  x = "cty",
  y = "hwy",
  col = "trans"
)
my_aes_list <- lapply(my_aes_list, tinycodet::form) # change strings into formulas
my_aes <- do.call(tinycodet::aes_pro, my_aes_list) # create aes
ggplot(mpg) + geom_point(my_aes) # plot
```